# Property does not exist on type. TypeScript

Tags: angularjs, typescript, controls, ionic2

I built a simple form that has some validation to it in Ionic 2. The form worked fine with ionic serve but wont work with ionic run. I belive the issue is not with ionic but with my type script. Somehow I must not be importing the right thing or not defining the right propertires. Here is my code.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import {Validators, FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import {Http, Request, RequestMethod } from '@angular/http';


/*
  Generated class for the ContactUs page.

  See http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#navigation for more info on
  Ionic pages and navigation.
*/
@Component({
  selector: 'page-contact',
  templateUrl: 'contact.html'
})

export class Contact {

  inputGroup: FormGroup;

  buttonDisabled = true;
  fullNameError = false;
  emailError = false;
  subjectError = false;
  messageError = false;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private formBuilder: FormBuilder, http: Http) {

    this.inputGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    fullName: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.maxLength(30), Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z ]*'), Validators.required])],
    email: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
    subject: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.maxLength(30), Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z ]*'), Validators.required])],
    message: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.maxLength(500), Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z ]*'), Validators.required])],
     });

  }



adjustButton(){
    if(this.inputGroup.controls.fullName.valid == true) {
        this.fullNameError = false;
    } 

    if(this.inputGroup.controls.email.valid == true) {
        this.emailError = false; 
    }

    if(this.inputGroup.controls.subject.valid == true) {
        this.subjectError = false;
    }

    if(this.inputGroup.controls.message.valid == true) {
        this.messageError = false;
    }
  }

  something() {
    console.log("Something happened");
  }

  onClick() {
    // if the fullName field is not valid display error
    if(!this.inputGroup.controls.fullName.valid) {
        this.fullNameError = true;
    } else {
        this.fullNameError = false;
    }




    if(!this.inputGroup.controls.email.valid) {
        this.emailError = true;
    } else {
        this.emailError = false;
    }

    if(!this.inputGroup.controls.subject.valid) {
        this.subjectError = true;
    } else {
        this.subjectError = false;
    }

    if(!this.inputGroup.controls.message.valid) {
        this.messageError = true;
    } else {
        this.messageError = false;
    }
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('Hello ContactUs Page');
  }

}
```

Then Here is my error log.

```
01:23:43]  ngc: Error: Error at /Users/Zach/Desktop/badgerLoop/badgerloop_app_v2/.tmp/pages/contact/contact.ts:40:30: Property 'fullName' does not exist on type '{ [key: string]: AbstractControl; }'.
Error at /Users/Zach/Desktop/badgerLoop/badgerloop_app_v2/.tmp/pages/contact/contact.ts:44:30: Property 'email' does not exist on type '{ [key: string]: AbstractControl; }'.
Error at /Users/Zach/Desktop/badgerLoop/badgerloop_app_v2/.tmp/pages/contact/contact.ts:48:30: Property 'subject' does not exist on type '{ [key: string]: AbstractControl; }'.
Error at /Users/Zach/Desktop/badgerLoop/badgerloop_app_v2/.tmp/pages/contact/contact.ts:52:30: Property 'message' does not exist on type '{ [key: string]: AbstractControl; }'.
Error at /Users/Zach/Desktop/badgerLoop/badgerloop_app_v2/.tmp/pages/contact/contact.ts:63:31: Property 'fullName' does not exist on type '{ [key: string]: AbstractControl; }'.
Error at /Users/Zach/Desktop/badgerLoop/badgerloop_app_v2/.tmp/pages/contact/contact.ts:72:31: Property 'email' does not exist on type '{ [key: string]: AbstractControl; }'.
Error at /Users/Zach/Desktop/badgerLoop/badgerloop_app_v2/.tmp/pages/contact/contact.ts:78:31: Property 'subject' does not exist on type '{ [key: string]: AbstractControl; }'.
Error at /Users/Zach/Desktop/badgerLoop/badgerloop_app_v2/.tmp/pages/contact/contact.ts:84:31: Property 'message' does not exist on type '{ [key: string]: AbstractControl; }'.
Error at /Users/Zach/Desktop/badgerLoop/badgerloop_app_v2/.tmp/pages/contact/contact.ngfactory.ts:788:41: Property 'fullName' does not exist on type 'Contact'.
Error at /Users/Zach/Desktop/badgerLoop/badgerloop_app_v2/.tmp/pages/contact/contact.ngfactory.ts:820:41: Property 'email' does not exist on type 'Contact'.
Error at /Users/Zach/Desktop/badgerLoop/badgerloop_app_v2/.tmp/pages/contact/contact.ngfactory.ts:857:41: Property 'subject' does not exist on type 'Contact'.
Error at /Users/Zach/Desktop/badgerLoop/badgerloop_app_v2/.tmp/pages/contact/contact.ngfactory.ts:889:41: Property 'message' does not exist on type 'Contact'.
Error at /Users/Zach/Desktop/badgerLoop/badgerloop_app_v2/.tmp/pages/contact/contact.ngfactory.ts:1175:43: Property 'fullName' does not exist on type 'Contact'.
Error at /Users/Zach/Desktop/badgerLoop/badgerloop_app_v2/.tmp/pages/contact/contact.ngfactory.ts:1190:43: Property 'email' does not exist on type 'Contact'.
Error at /Users/Zach/Desktop/badgerLoop/badgerloop_app_v2/.tmp/pages/contact/contact.ngfactory.ts:1205:43: Property 'subject' does not exist on type 'Contact'.
Error at /Users/Zach/Desktop/badgerLoop/badgerloop_app_v2/.tmp/pages/contact/contact.ngfactory.ts:1220:43: Property 'message' does not exist on type 'Contact'.
    at check (/Users/Zach/Desktop/badgerLoop/badgerloop_app_v2/node_modules/@angular/tsc-wrapped/src/tsc.js:31:15)
    at Tsc.typeCheck (/Users/Zach/Desktop/badgerLoop/badgerloop_app_v2/node_modules/@angular/tsc-wrapped/src/tsc.js:86:9)
    at /Users/Zach/Desktop/badgerLoop/badgerloop_app_v2/node_modules/@angular/tsc-wrapped/src/main.js:33:23
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:606:11)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3


[01:23:43]  ngc: Compilation failed

[01:23:43]  ngc failed:  NGC encountered an error
[01:23:43]  Error: NGC encountered an error
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/Zach/Desktop/badgerLoop/badgerloop_app_v2/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/ngc.js:62:24)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:334:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:498:12)

Error running ionic app script "build": Error: NGC encountered an error
```

Can someone please tell me why I am receiving these errors?

Comment: I have the exact same issue when running `ionic build browser`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to solve this by not using dot notation to access map properties.

You are using dot notation in your controller, (eg. `!this.inputGroup.controls.fullName.valid`). I think that is fine, but if you are using dot notation in your template, (eg. `*ngIf="inputGroup.controls.fullName"`), you will have this problem due to differences between the just in time compiler (JIT) and the ahead of time compiler (AoT). I think `ionic serve` uses JIT, but `ionic build` uses AoT.

In your template, change usages to look like this: `inputGroup.controls['fullName']`

[This](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11709#issuecomment-248240109) thread helped me understand the problem.

```
$ ionic info

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.3.1
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.0
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.0-beta.1
OS: Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS 
Node Version: v6.6.0
```

Comment: I fixed this within my controller and added a definition for each control such as 'fullName: any;' Thanks so much!

Comment: I like this solution, but another option is to set `"fullTemplateTypeCheck": false` in `"angularCompilorOptions"` inside your app's `tsconfig.json` file. Course you should only consider doing this if you're positive that the compiler is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try setting the attributes like that (**with apexes**) :

```
this.inputGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    'fullName': [...],
    'email': [...],
    'subject': [...],
    'message': [...],
});
```

and in your .html:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <ion-item>
       <ion-label>FullName</ion-label>
       <ion-input formControlName="fullName"></ion-input> 
    </ion-item>
</form>
```

edit: This is a **working** example in RC.1:

**.ts**

```
export class RootRegistrazione {
    myForm: FormGroup;
    userInfo: {phone: string} = {phone: ''};

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
        this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
              'phone': ['', this.phoneValidator.bind(this)]              
        });
    }

    phoneValidator(control: FormControl): {[s: string]: boolean} {
        if (control.value !== '') {
            if (!control.value.match(/^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{7}$/)) {
                return {invalidPhone: true};
            }
        }
    }

    isValid(field: string) {
        let formField = this.myForm.get(field);
        return formField.valid || formField.pristine;
    }

    onSubmit() {
        console.log('submitting form');
    }
}
```

**.html**

```
<ion-content padding class="registration">
    <ion-list>
        <form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
            <ion-item>
                <ion-label color="primary" stacked>Cellphone</ion-label>
                <ion-input [(ngModel)]="userInfo.phone" formControlName="phone" type="text"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
            <p *ngIf="!isValid('phone')" color="danger" padding-left>Invalid number, expected format "012-3456789"</p>

            <button ion-button full color="favorite" type="submit" [disabled]="!myForm.valid">Create Account</button>
        </form>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Hope i'd have helped you now :)

Comment: @NieldeWet check added code if maybe could help fixing your issue :)

Comment: The reason why your code is **working** is because you don't use dot notation in your html template. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you import FormControl and assign the input values with "formcontrolname".

In your HTML use

```
<ion-input formControlName="fullName" type="text"></ion-input>
```

In your TS:

```
public fullName: FormControl;
 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private formBuilder: FormBuilder, http: Http) {
    this.fullName = new FormControl("", Validators.compose([Validators.maxLength(30), Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z ]*'), Validators.required]));
    this.inputGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    fullName: this.fullName,
});
```

Comment: i am not sure why you are getting Abstract Control in errors. Are you using it. Guess instead of AbstractControl only we are using FormControl. Make sure you have "@angular/forms": "^2.0.0" installed. What is the version of ionic you are using?