# Ionic3, Typescript - Ignore Typescript Errors “property ' ' does not exist on value of type ' '”

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I've gone through [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18083389/ignore-typescript-errors-property-does-not-exist-on-value-of-type) (and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40564922/typescript-error-property-does-not-exist-on-type) as well) to find a solution to my problem.

I want to ignore these errors:

`Property 'payload' does not exist on type 'Matatu'.`

`Property 'key' does not exist on type 'Matatu'.`

I've tried declaring variables to 'override' the type system, but it hasn't worked.

Here is my `.ts` code, and what I've attempted so far:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, ActionSheetController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFireList, AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Matatu } from '../../models/matatu/matatu.interface';
/* imports */

declare var payload;
declare var key;

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-owner-dash',
  templateUrl: 'owner-dash.html',
})
export class OwnerDashPage {

  matatuListRef$: AngularFireList<Matatu>;
  matatuListAsync$: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private database: AngularFireDatabase, public actionShtCrtl: ActionSheetController) {

    this.matatuListRef$ = this.database.list('matatu-list');
    this.matatuListAsync$ = this.matatuListRef$.snapshotChanges();

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
   //stuff 
  }

  selectMatatu(matatu: Matatu){
    this.actionShtCrtl.create({
      title: `${matatu.payload.val().matNumberPlate}`,
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Edit',
          handler: () => {
            //stuff
          }          
        },
        {
          text: 'Delete',
          role: 'destructive',
          handler: () => {
            this.matatuListRef$.remove(matatu.key);
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          role: 'cancel',
          handler: () => {
            //do something
          }
        }
      ]
    }).present();
  }


}
```

Here's the `Matatu` structure:

```
export interface Matatu {
    $key?: string;
    matNumberPlate: string;
    matSacco: string;
    matDriver: string;
    matAccessCode: string;
    matStatus: string;
    matTracker: string;
    matLocation: string;

}
```

How do I cast the property to any type?

Comment: Could you please also add the definition of the `Matatu` type?

Comment: It's an interface. There it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I cast the property to any type?

If you just want to cast that in order to avoid the typescript error, you could do something like this:

```
// ...
title: `${(<any>matatu).payload.val().matNumberPlate}`,
// ...
```

And

```
// ...
this.matatuListRef$.remove((<any>matatu).key);
// ...
```

That way `matatu` would be cast to `any` and the error should be gone.

---

What I'd recommend, if you can modify the `Matatu` interface, would be to add those two properties there instead:

```
export interface Matatu {
    $key?: string;
    matNumberPlate: string;
    matSacco: string;
    matDriver: string;
    matAccessCode: string;
    matStatus: string;
    matTracker: string;
    matLocation: string;

    // New properties are optional
    payload?: any;
    key?: any;
}
```

That way you don't need to cast the `matatu` property since both `payload` and `key` are part of the definition of the `Matatu` type (and both are of type `any`).